# Where idAccoun='' give back all row with idAccount 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a System-Account, with the Account ID 0.

The problem is if I make the SQL call:

```
SELECT `id`,`name`,`streetName`,`streetNr` FROM `table` WHERE `idAccount` =''
```

Type idAccount = INT

The MySQL give me back all rows with the idAccount 0

I think the reason is because '' = 0.

Comment: Don't compare numbers to strings.  That seems like a pretty simple rule to follow.

Comment: Thats true if you have 0 but if not =) then you do not get a SQL error if you have = '' ( = , error)

Answer (score 1):

'' seems to be equal to 0, if the datatype of the column is int.
My approch would be:

```
SELECT `id`,`name`,`streetName`,`streetNr` FROM `table` WHERE `idAccount` = NULL
```

Worked for me as SQL query in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Yes NULL is work but for this you have to rebuild mysqli_real_escape_string because NULL = error =)